# Explaining a function that converts uint32 to hex

Tags: c

I would like someone to explain to me this weird function that is found in the code base in my work.

```
bool uint32tox(const UINT32 input, UINT8 *str)
{
    UINT32 val = input;
    INT16  i;
    UINT16  j = 0;

    if (str == NULL) return(false);

    for (i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4) {
        UINT8 sval = (val >> i) & 0x0F;
        str[j++] = (sval < 10u) ? sval + '0' : sval - 10 + 'A';
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return(true);
}
```

why anding with 0x0F, why i starts with 28.

Comment: `0x0F` is binary `0000 1111` which masks off the left 4 bit of a number. Remember, one "hex digit" (0-9 A-F) always encodes 4 bits. The operator `val >> i` right-shifts the value by `i` bits, and `i` is decremented by `4` in each iteration, to go to the next 4-bit hex-digit. And it starts at 28 because a `UINT32` is 32 bits long, so for the first 4 bits to be display, you have to bitshift the number `32 - 4 = 28` bits to left, sothat the first iteration will output Bits 0 to 4 as hex digit into the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to comment the code a bit

```
/*
  Convert an unsigned 32-bit (assuming UINT32 to mean uint32_t or similar) large
  integer to a hexadecimal representation
*/
bool uint32tox(const UINT32 input, UINT8 *str)
{
    UINT32 val = input;
    INT16  i;
    UINT16  j = 0;

    if (str == NULL) return(false);

    for (i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4) {
        // Shift input by i bits to the right and snip of the rightmost 4 bits
        /*

            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

            with i = 28 sval contains the leftmost four bits 28 - 31
            with i = 24 sval contains bits 24-27
            with i = 20 sval contains bits 20-23
            with i = 16 sval contains bits 16-19
            with i = 12 sval contains bits 12-15
            with i =  8 sval contains bits  8-11
            with i =  4 sval contains bits  4- 7
            with i =  4 sval contains bits  0- 3
        */
        UINT8 sval = (val >> i) & 0x0F;
        // If sval is smaller than ten we can use a base ten digit
        // that gets constructed by adding the numerical value of ASCII '0'
        // to sval (the digits 0-9 are guaranteed to be in order without gaps).
        // If sval is bigger we need a hexdigit, one of A, B, C, D, E, F.
        // These are normally consecutive at least in ASCII, so you can handle it
        // like the other branch and just add the numerical value of 'A' instead
        str[j++] = (sval < 10u) ? sval + '0' : sval - 10 + 'A';
    }
    // terminate the UINT8 array such that it can be used as a C-string
    str[j] = '\0';
    return(true);
}
```

Comment: for correction, the left most four bits is 28-31 not 30

Comment: @deamentiaemundi - This is how a good developer writes that kind of code!

Comment: @FeryalBadili are you making fun of this, or its really good code ? because I suspect

Comment: @FeryalBadili I would argue this is good code, as it isn't checking the buffer's size, and perhaps should be using some built-in functions, but I guess you are dazzled by the commenting style :)

Comment: I am impressed by the answer that deamentiaemundi provided and my complement was for his/her answer.

Comment: @TomerW - I don't think Feryal said it was good code, (s)he said this is how a good developer writes code ;)

Comment: @Tomer W - Yes, you are right. Although the bug that you found is valid, the level of details in the comments are very impressive. I just had to say it :)

Comment: @andreahmed Oopsy! Embarassing typo corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first and foremost, this function is broken, as it has no size for the *str buffer, can cause malicious attacks, or plain buggy overflows.

secondly, you can use `sprintf(strOut, "%x",input);` instead of this function.

### Third, i'll explain this function:

there is a trick, where each Hex digit, is 4 binary bits bits:

```
0100 1111 0010 1101 0011 1110 1111 0000 >> 83,022,831
4 =4 15=F 2 =2 13=D 3 =3 14=E 15=F 0 =0 >> 0x4F2D3EF
```

1. loops starts at `i=28`
2. shift val 28 places right >> leaves 4 Left Bit [28-31] as Right most bits.
3. mask with 0x00000F >> leaves only the 4 right most bits.
4. if the number is smaller than 10 (where we start counting with Letters), add the ASCII of '0' (e.g 3 will '0' is 48 + 3 = 51 = '3')
5. if the number is bigger then 10, then subtract 10, and add the ASCII of 'A' (e.g 14 will be 14-10=4 > 'A' is 65 + 4 = 69 = 'E')
6. subtract 4 from i, therefore shifting 24 bits and doing the same on bits [24-27]
   until `i=0` is processed.

Comment: why would I need the size of str ?

Comment: what I I want to convert a signed char to hex. is just the loop will start from i=4 ? is that what needs to be changed ?

Comment: @andreahmed if you dont know the size of *str, you dont know how much can fit in, and prevent overflows... e.g.  `char s[4];char password[4]; u32tohex(0x12349999, s);` this will cause password to be "9999".
or possibly begin a ROP attack, and so, checking buffers is a must!

Comment: how would I fix it please. I need the to see where is the problem exactly.

Comment: c/cpp does not check your array size, `int a[4]; a[6] =51;` is compiled cleanly, but a[6] writes over memory you didn't really set for it, did you?